# How can I pass a dataType as an argument to create an ArrayList of this type?

Tags: java, arraylist

Let's say I have something like:

```
public void do(DataType type) {
    ArrayList<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DataType>();
    doStuff();
}
```

In some cases I want to create an arrayList of another type by passing the type as a parameter, how can I do this in Java?

Comment: This is not possible in Java.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html try generics

Comment: Check: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/ .

Comment: You can not pass a datatype as an argument to a method, you can only pass the value of that datatype.

Comment: BTW `do` can not be method name. It is reserved word.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to pass an object as a parameter, but a data type. Generics in method parameters don't help with this, and I believe Parasu and Ankit are right in that it is not possible at all.

Comment: What about `void doSomething(Class<T> clazz)`?

Comment: I am not sure if that will suit your use case. But, you can make use of `instanceof` keyword. This keyword will allow you to check for the object type you have.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this..

```
    public <T> void stuff(T type){
        ArrayList<T> arrayList = new ArrayList<T>();
        doStuff();
    }
```

generics may be helpfull you if you want to create sigle object that represent it, but when you want a simple private attribute the easy way is this.

Comment: and how can I know what T is, in the code? Something like `if(T.dataType.equals(Integer)) {
    doStuff()
}
else if(T.dataType.equals(Double)) {
doSomethingElse()
}`

Comment: use instanceof keyword

Comment: how do I cast the ArrayList to a double, if I want to?

Comment: In this code, the parameter is an object, not a data type. This is not what the OP asked for. This code allows, for example, stuff(new Integer(42)) (explicit boxing for clarity), but not stuff(Integer), which is what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want something like this:

```
public static <T>List<T> makeList(T t) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    // doStuff();
    return list;
}
```

And usage of `makeList` function:

```
makeList("String list").add("new String"); // ok
makeList("String list").add(5);            // compile error
```

Answer (score 1):

More universal approach is the following:

```
public <T extends IDataType> void doSomething(T type) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    doStuff();
}
```

where: `DataType` implements `IDataType`

In this case you can use any type which implements `IDataType`

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't allow to pass class types as method parameters. As far as I know, the closest you can get is this :

```
import java.util.*;

class MyClass<T> {

    public void stuff() {
        ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
        //doStuff();
    }

}

class Test {        
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new MyClass<String>()).stuff();
        (new MyClass<Integer>()).stuff();
    }
}
```

So you would need to instanciate the class each time you need it.

Comment: I do believe we can pass class types as method params. Please see my code and let me know if that doesn't solve what OP is looking for.

Comment: In your code, the value of the parameter is an object representing a class type, which is not the same thing as a class type. It also solves the OP's problem, of course. The main difference is that your approach uses reflection, mine doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public static <T> List<T> doSomething(Class<T> clazz){
    ArrayList<T> testList = new ArrayList<T>();
    return testList;
    // more code
}
```

and you can invoke this like :

```
List<Integer> intList = doSomething(Integer.class);
intList.add(1);
List<String> stringList = doSomething(String.class);
stringList.add("test");
```

and if you want to restrict the type of Class you need, you could use T extends youDataType. If what @subhash has explained is not the one you are looking for, and if what @zoyd explains is true, then i believe this could be of some use.